# How to get JSP custom value inside another JSP custom tag

Tags: java, jsp, tags, jstl, jsp-tags

I got two tags as below:

Tag 1 this will return a string that can be displayed on browser:

```
<dn:account><%= account_username %></dn:account>
```

Tag 2

```
<token:output username=""></token:output>
```

Instead of displaying the tag 1, I want pass it to tag 2 like below:

```
<token:output username="<dn:account><%= account_username %></dn:account>"></token:output>
```

The problem is I'm not getting the value of the username, I'm getting this entire tag return back.

What are the solutions.

TQ.

Answer (score 0):

To get values there is `&{}`

```
<c:set var="aVariable" value="aValue" /> 
 <tt:anotherTag attr1="${aVariable}" />
```

check this out if there ia any problem let me know.

By the way check  this. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/819-3669/bnalj/index.html

Answer (score 0):

With the previous annotation I think it´s not good enough, you need to specify the scope as request.

```
   <c:set var="aVariable" value="aValue" scope="request" />
```

Comment: means that can I do like this : <c:set var="aVar" value="<dn:account><%= account_username %></dn:account>" scope="request"/>

Comment: sure, I dont see why not

Comment: the output i getting is ${aVar}. Any thing i missed.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer.

Its should be like this:

```
<dn:account>
<token:output username="<%= account_username %>"></token:output>
</dn:account>
```

Thanks for those helping.